# KVM install of Fedora hangs using VNC console

Tags: fedora, kvm-virtualization, vnc

I'm trying to install Fedora 15 using the KVM VNC console. I can create the virtual machine just fine and can connect to the VNC console. A bunch of text scrolls by and then it hangs. I presume this is where the installer would be switching to the GUI but the VNC console can't cope.

How can I either convince VNC to switch the the graphical view or force the installer to be text-only?

For the latter, I have tried adding the "text" kernel option when I boot the VM, but it still hangs at the same place.

The host OS is Ubuntu 10 LTS.

#### Edit

Fedora will be running in a headless, text-only mode. I won't be using its GUI when it's running. In other words, this is for a server installation. I know FC can run in less than 1GB because I run one on a [Linode](http://linode.com) with just 512MB.

#### Edit

Solution to the installer problem: boost the amount of memory to at least 768MB. It runs much better. After the installation was complete, I was able to reduce the memory footprint to 384MB and could go even lower if I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM do you have in your VM? F15 installer is comfortable at about 1GB.

Gnome-shell uses video acceleration for its functionality, but from what I read in this release there's a fail-back mechanism for environments that don't provide hardware acceleration.

Comment: 1GB seems outlandishly high. I was giving the VM about 384MB.

Comment: See e.g. http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-262156.html for comments -- F15 is a memory hog during installation. There's hope for change with F16, but for now you have no chance of success with 384 MB.